# JVM crashando de forma aleatória

Tags: java, jvm

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc501ddca87, pid=2944, tid=0x00007fc4c41ab700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_201-b09) (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.201-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6cfa87]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*) [clone .constprop.109]+0x27
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fc4fc43f000):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=2974, stack(0x00007fc4c40ab000,0x00007fc4c41ac000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000035
```

A cada três execuções do meu software, duas me retornam isso. Tentei debugar para achar onde isso tá rolando, mas não achei. Alguma ideia do que pode estar causando isso? Eu pesquisei e não achei NADA. Pode ser só meu computador?

Já tentei `ulimit -c unlimited` e não funcionou.

Estudei o comportamento dos núcleos da CPU e memória RAM durante a execução do software e ambos apresentaram comportamentos normais (não aumentaram nem diminuiram, ficaram como sempre).

Estou trabalhando com FXML se isso muda algo, mas nenhum framework a mais.

Edit: Debuguei muito mais o código e vi que o crash ocorre nesse método dentro de uma classe do Java (classe Scene.java):

```
    @Override
    public void keyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent)
    {
        impl_processKeyEvent(keyEvent);
    }
```

Comment: Vou dar um palpite, pode ser JVM bugada. Seu PC sofreu queda de energia ou desligamento acidental ultimamente? Talvez desinstalar e reinstalar a JDK resolva.

Comment: Sofreu, sim! Eu fiquei com medo de ser algo no meu software, mas tá muito estranho ele crashar aleatoriamente assim. Só desinstalar o JDK serve? To pensando em fazer uma reinstalação completa do Java...

Comment: Até onde sei reinstalar a JDK é "fazer a reinstalação completa do Java" (incluindo aí a JRE, se ela não foi instalada à parte), mas faz aí o que for mais completo.

Comment: Eu reinstalei o JDK. A principio, os erros pararam. Agora, fui debugar um código e ele voltou a dar o MESMO erro. Ele tinha parado, isso não faz sentido...

Comment: A única dica que posso dar é reinstalar JDK, reinstalar JRE's (Java Runtime Environment) que estiverem instaladas junto, fora isso não sei como ajudar mais.

Comment: Sobrou só reinstalar o Eclipse ou Netbeans ou a IDE que estiver usando. Depois disso é reinstalar o sistema operacional...

Comment: Estou usando o IntelliJ. O lance todo é que eu procurei muito por algum motivo, algo que dissesse o que pode ser... mas acho que é melhor formatar, mesmo. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é um [BUG](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141687) conhecido do Java, que foi mencionado apenas no Java 10.

Esse bug ocorre quando você tenta manipular um elemento gráfico dentro de algum contexto externo. No meu caso, se dava por causa desse trecho:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
stage.close();
```

Geralmente isso acontecia após uma tela de login, onde se tenta fechar o Stage (ou Frame), fazendo a JVM crashar.

Solução para isso:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
});
```

Comment: Tem fonte oficial de que conhecem esse bug?

Comment: Tem sim. Esqueci de colocar, mas vou atualizar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se que sua BIOS possui a Virtualização de CPU ativada!

Alguns computadores não possuem o sistema de virtualização, isso causa problemas em qualquer aplicativo que necessite vitualizar seu CPU.